# Client Receives no data from Server

Tags: java, sockets, client, no-data

I am trying to make a texting application between multiple clients, and a single server. The only problem is, the client receives no data from the server. Here is the code for the client side classes.

```
package client;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client implements Runnable{
private ClientServer server;
private Scanner in;
private Thread thread;
private boolean running;
private ArrayList<String> messages;

private Client(){
    in = new Scanner(System.in);
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    messages = new ArrayList<>();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Client();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    boolean worked = false;
    while (!worked){
        System.out.println("Type in the server id.");
        String input = in.nextLine();
        try {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
            try{
                server = new ClientServer(new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(), number), this);
                worked = true;
            }
            catch (UnknownHostException e){
                System.out.println("Could not connect. Unknown Host.");
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("Could not connect. Invalid id.");
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("That was not a number.");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Username: ");
    server.send(in.nextLine());
    while (running){
        for (String message : messages){
            System.out.println(message);
        }
        messages.clear();
        server.send(in.nextLine());
    }
}

public void print(String message){
    System.out.println("Working");
    messages.add(message);
}
}
```

---

```
package client;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ClientServer implements Runnable{
    private PrintStream out;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private Socket server;
    private Thread thread;
    private Client client;
        public ClientServer(Socket server, Client client){
        this.server = server;
        this.client = client;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        try {
            out = new PrintStream(server.getOutputStream());
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
        }
        catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (server.isConnected()){
        try {
            client.print(in.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void send(String message){
    out.println(message);
}
}
```

And is the code for the server classes.

```
package server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerClient implements Runnable {
    private Socket client;
    private PrintStream out;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private Server server;
    private String clientName;
    private Thread clientThread;

    public ServerClient(Socket client, Server server){
        this.client = client;
        this.server = server;
        try {
            out = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    clientThread = new Thread(this);
    clientThread.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        clientName = in.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    out.println("test");
    boolean running = true;
    while (client.isConnected() && running) {
        try {
            server.messageReceived(server.getClients().indexOf(this), clientName + ": " + in.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        client.close();
        server.getClients().remove(this);
        clientThread.join();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void send(String message) {
    out.println(message);
    System.out.println("Working");
}
}
```

---

```
package server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Server implements Runnable {
private boolean running;
private ArrayList<ServerClient> clients;
private int port;
private ServerSocket serverSocket;

private Server(){
    port = 9999;
    running = true;
    clients = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean worked = false;
    while (!worked) {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            worked = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            port++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Port: " + port);
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Server();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(running){
        try {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            clients.add(new ServerClient(socket, this));
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void messageReceived(int clientNumber, String message){
    for (int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++) {
        if(i != clientNumber) clients.get(i).send(message);
    }
}

public ArrayList<ServerClient> getClients() {
    return clients;
}
}
```

The send() method is called in ServerClient, but the client never advances past in.nextLine(), meaning it is not recieving any data. I can confirm, however, that the server does recieve data from the client, but not the other way around. Can anyone see why, because I certianly can't.
Thank you.

Comment: `isConnected()` is not a valid loop condition. It will never become false. You should instead be testing the result of `readLine()` for null every time it is called.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I changed it, but it didn't fix the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

I simply needed to start the thread in the ClientServer class. The client was receiving data. It's just that the thread responsible for reading that data was never started.